# Change publisher name on specific app in google play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

We have multiple app in google play console and all of them are with same publisher name. Is it possible to replace one of those to different?

Comment: There can be only 1 publisher name associated with a google play console account. If you have multiple Accounts then Yes you can change the publisher name.

Comment: Ok understood thanks